# necesito que un botón me pueda mandar a diferentes layout dependiendo de que se encuentre escrito dentro de un textview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo un botón, un textView y 4 layouts, 1 layout es el main, donde está el botón y el TextView, las demas layout son "entrada, imagenes, informacion", entonces si en el textView escribo "entrada" y preciono el botón, me manda al layout de entrada, pero si en el TextView tengo escrito "imagenes" me mande al layout de imagenes, el poco codigo que tenia era usar un if dentro de un setOnnClickListener pero no funciona

```
        final Button MandarALayout = findViewById(R.id.Ingresar);

        final TextView respuesta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NombreLayout);
        final String serType = respuesta.getText().toString();


        MandarALayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (serType=="entrada"){
                    Intent mandarEntrada = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Entrada.class);
                    startActivity(mandarEntrada);
                }
                if (serType=="imagenes"){
                    Intent mandarImagenes = new Intent(MainActivity.this, imagenes.class);
                    startActivity(mandarImagenes);
                }
                if (serType=="informacion"){
                    Intent mandarInformacion = new Intent (MainActivity.this, informacion.class);
                    startActivity(mandarInformacion);
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que has intentado?

Comment: son Layouts o Activities?  como se va a escoger la opción(entrada, imagenes, informacion)? para esto ultimo creo que sebe ser un EditText, no un TextView

Answer (score 1):

Hola en ese caso tendrías que usar equals

```
if (serType.equals("entrada")){
                    Intent mandarEntrada = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Entrada.class);
                    startActivity(mandarEntrada);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar lo siguiente :

```
MandarALayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(serType.getText().toString()){
     case "valorA":
           Intent mandarImagenes = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityA.class);
           startActivity(mandarImagenes);
     break;
     case "valorB":
           Intent mandarImagenes = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityA.class);
           startActivity(mandarImagenes);
     break;
     default:
           Intent mandarImagenes = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityA.class);
           startActivity(mandarImagenes);
   }
}
```